# SharedPreference not synchronized with Service when service run as different process

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I'd created a service as a process. I'm saving some data to Shared Preference inside MyFirebaseMessagingService class. But When I try to retrieve that data inside MyService, It returns empty.

For saving the data I'm using this code

```
val preferences = getSharedPreferences("Sample", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val editor = preferences?.edit()
editor?.putString("shiftStartTime", map["shift_start_time"].toString())
editor?.putString("shiftEndTime", map["shift_end_time"].toString())
editor?.commit()
```

Here is the code to access the data in service

```
 override fun onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate")
    initializeLocationManager()

    mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Sample", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
 }
  override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: $location")
       val startTime = mPreferences!!.getString("shiftStartTime", "") 
     // This Start time always return as empty
 }
```

Here is Manifest file declaration

```
 <service
  android:name=".location.MyService"
  android:process=":my_service"/>
```

Comment: are you on the same thread while setting the data and retrieving it? I have a feeling you are setting the data in an async thread and trying to retrieve it from the main thread. Please post more code from where you are setting the data.

Comment: I'm saving the data in FirebaseMessagingService class, and retrieving in a Different Service, Which is run as process..

Comment: What is the delay between writing and reading? Milliseconds? Seconds? Minutes?

Comment: I think its in seconds 20-30 sec.. because location service is started when app is start and on every location change it get the data from shared preference.  Data saved in preference when i got the notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reliably share preferences or data across different processes you should use something other than `SharedPreferences`, like a `ContentProvider`.

In API 23 the `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` flag [was deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS):

> Applications should not attempt to use it. Instead, they should use an
>   explicit cross-process data management approach such as
>   `ContentProvider`.

If you nevertheless want to use `SharedPreferences` try not using a dedicated process for your `Service`.

Comment: Thanks Markus, I'll try this.